# Memberships Automated Discount

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, cividiscount

I'm new here and looking forward to meeting Civi users.

My query is this: I have set up a series of memberships, bronze, silver and gold. For Gold I want to offer an automated discount for other services.

I added a discount code and set the discount option to be automatic. However, when I 'view' the discount, I can't see that it will be automatic and when I test it there is no discount code for 'Gold Members' on the other services I offer.

I have checked the contribute set up page and I can't see anyplace that I should be ticking 'discount' so the discount option automatically shows on the contribution pages.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Paula

[image]
[image]

Comment: asking the obvious here, but you say "and when I test it", do you mean 'as a contact that has (only) a Gold Membership'?

Comment: I can't see from your screen shot what the discount applies to. (events, membership, etc)?

Comment: Hi KilakwaBT
Thanks, the screenshot shows the discount I set up for other items where a Gold Member can get the discount. The 2nd screenshot shows nothing on the automatic membership line but the first shows I did set it up to allow Gold Members to buy other services for the automatic discounted price.

Comment: HI Petednz. I have tested it as a Gold Member and an anon user. Regards
Paula

Comment: CiviDiscount manages discount codes that can be used for membership and events. You specify what memberships/events the code can be used against and as an advanced feature, you can setup automatic discounts to save them needing to type in a code. In your situation, they are already members so you could use it to give them discounts on events.  But your first screenshot does not show a 'Discount for events' section above the 'Discounts for memberships' suggesting that you don't have Events enabled ... When you say 'the other services I offer' - what are those in Civi terms?

Comment: Thanks Aidan, the other services are set up on different contribution pages. I'm sure this is simple, I'm just not sure what I have not done to get the Gold Members to receive the automatic discount for these other services. Can you advise? Thanks, Paula

Comment: I'm not sure that cividiscount is set up to work at all with non-membership contribution pages that it sounds like you are using. (If you think about it... for most nonprofits non membership contributions are just donations and it doesn't make a ton of sense to 'discount a donation'). I haven't had any luck with that so far and have set up these items as drupal webforms or cannibalised "events".

Comment: Thanks Eli, as you mention, I wonder if civi can't actually do what I am trying to do. I know it can give an automated discount off an event, but I am trying to make it give an automated discount off a normal contribution page. Any advice? Thanks, Paula